# Is there a shorter way to write this code?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I want to return a list of the values in the binary tree.
Is there a shorter and more efficient way to write the method for numbers?

Thank you.

```
class BTNode(object):
    """A node in a binary tree."""

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        """(BTNode, object, BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
        Initialize this node to store item and have children left and right,
        as well as depth 0.
        """
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.depth = 0  # the depth of this node in a tree

    def number(self) -> list:
        lst = []

        if self.right is None and self.left is None:
            lst.append(self.item)
        else:
            lst.append(self.item)
        if self.left:
            left = self.left.number()
            lst.extend(left)
        if self.right:
            right = self.right.number()
            lst.extend(right)
        return lst
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Looks like python.  Do you really need the first if statement in def number?  Both the then and else parts look the same.

Comment: Why don't you try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? This question seems more suitable for those sites.

Comment: Thanks for the links, will do.
And the above code is python.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review, that is off topic, it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a generator rather than a list, you can write the code quite neatly.

```
def number(self):
    yield self.item
    for child in self.left, self.right:
        if child: yield from child.number()
```

I've never seen the type annotations you have in Python before. Is that a Python 3 thing?

Comment: I found this(type annotations): http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: All I know is that Python 3 supports this type of annotation. Some of my instructors prefer it this way, so I've adopted this style of annotation as well. By the way, do you know of another way to implement this method without the use of generators? Thanks!

Comment: `def number_list(self): return list(self.number())`

Answer (score 0):

I've got a nonrecursive iterator for returning the values in a tree (treap) at
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treap

To get from an iterator to a list is just a matter of wrapping the iterator like list(it())

Last I heard, 'yield from' was slow.